# uploading a file with python

Tags: python-2.7, upload, python-requests

I'm pretty new to programming and i'm trying to write a program that will upload a file to a website. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. The file isn't getting uploaded. I think my issue is to do with the multipart form data but i wouldn't be surprised if i'm wrong.

```
import requests, os, sys

url = "myURL"

uploadFile = {'ILWinterConditions.kmz': open('C:\\Users\\JOC-001\\Documents\\GIS\\IDOT\\ILWinterConditions.kmz', 'rb')}

payload = {

    'fname': 'myfname',

    'lname': 'mylname',

    'org': 'myorg',

    'phone': 'myphone',

    'email': 'myemail',

    'datadescrip': 'mydatadesc',

    'uploadedfile': 'C:\\Users\\JOC-001\\Documents\\GIS\\IDOT\\ILWinterConditions.kmz'

}

r = requests.post(url, verify = False, auth=('myUsername','mypassword'), files=uploadFile, data=payload)
print r.content
```

Below is the response I'm getting from print and the file is not being uploaded

```
<head>

    <title>*I have censored this*</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>

</head>



<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Add other extensions here if we want to allow other files to be

        // uploaded.  Check is not case-sensitive.  Will also be checked on

        // the server.

        var allowedExtensions = [ "kml", "kmz", "jpg", "png", "csv" ];

        var maxSize = 12 * 1024*1024;

        var errorMessage = "Only .csv, .kml, .kmz, .jpg, or .png files up to 12MB are accepted!";



        // Checks that the file meets our criteria.  This is just for user

        // convenience-- to catch problems before they attempt to do the

        // upload.  The file will be checked again on the server too.

        function FileIsOkay() {

            var fileInput = document.getElementById('uploadedFile');



            // First check the file's extension

            var fileName = fileInput.value;

            var fileExtension = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

            var extensionOK = false;

            for (var i=0; i<allowedExtensions.length; ++i) {

                if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i].toLowerCase()) {

                    extensionOK = true;

                    break;

                }

            }

            if (! extensionOK) {

                alert(errorMessage);

                return false;

            }



            // Now check the file's size.

            // Doesn't work in IE, but that's okay... it'll get checked on

            // the server any way.

            if (fileInput.files) {

                var file = fileInput.files[0];

                if (file) {

                    if (file.size > maxSize) {

                        alert(errorMessage);

                        return false;

                    }

                }

            }



            return true;

        }

    </script>



    <div class="title">

        <img src="webdavtitle.png"/>

    </div>



    <form method="POST" action="uploader.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return FileIsOkay();" class="fileForm">

        <table class="detailsTable">

            <tr>

                <td class="inputLabel">First Name:</td>

                <td class="inputField"><input type="text" name="fname" size="40"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td class="inputLabel">Last Name:</td>

                <td class="inputField"><input type="text" name="lname" size="40"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td class="inputLabel">Organization/Agency:</td>

                <td class="inputField"><input type="text" name="org" size="40"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td class="inputLabel">Phone (DSN or Com):</td>

                <td class="inputField"><input type="text" name="phone" size="40"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td class="inputLabel">Email:</td>

                <td class="inputField"><input type="text" name="email" size="40"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td class="inputLabel">Data Description:</td>

                <td class="inputField"><input type="text" name="datadescrip" size="40"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td class="inputLabel">

                    Choose a .kml, .kmz, .jpg,<br/>

                    or .png file to upload:

                </td>

                <td class="inputField">

                    <input id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedfile" size="40" type="file"/>

                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td></td>

                <td class="inputField"><input type="submit" value="Upload File"></input></td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>



    <div class="footer">

        <img border="0" src="horiz_grey_line.gif">

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

        <a href="I Have censored this"><img border="0" src="contacthelp.png"></a>

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

        <a href="*I have censored this*"><img border="0" src="nc_address.gif"></a>

        <a href="*I have censored this*"><img border="0" src="nc_webpolicy.gif"></a>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What is the value of url?

Comment: @Vincent Beltman, Do you NEED the url? Its a military website I'm hoping not to give it out if possible.

Comment: @VincentBeltman, I can give you the URL if necessary.

Comment: Make sure you have the right size. Is it possible to upload the file on the website with a browser?

Comment: @VincentBeltman, Yes it is. I can manually upload the file with no problems at all. I fill out all of the data fields list under multipart form data under the html response browse to my file and hit upload. But the code itself is not doing that. I feel as if I have written something wrong but I have no clue how to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I figured out the issue. the "uploadedFile" was written incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue with this code. It should have been

```
uploadFile = {'uploadedfile': open('C:\\Users\\JOC-001\\Documents\\GIS\\IDOT\\ILWinterConditions.kmz', 'rb')}
```

to fit the form data. and `'payload'` did not need the

`'uploadedfile': 'C:\\Users\\JOC-001\\Documents\\GIS\\IDOT\\ILWinterConditions.kmz'`